# Android graphics Color in xml

Tags: android, xml, colors, android-edittext

in my app I have some `text.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)`. Now I would like to use the same color from this class in my xml file for other fields whose color doesn't change.

All I found in the xml files is `@color` which contains only entry "black", and `@android:color/` that also has some other weird entries like "dark_gray", but no simple "gray".

How can I get the same colors in my xml files and in my code, withouth creating my own resource. I belive this has to be possible, cause it would just be weird otherwise.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the problem in creating your color resource file once and call it everywhere,

Comment: It's really not a problem, but if there is a way of doing it without making my own resource, I would like to know how. And this seems to be such a basic thing, I would feel like reinventing hot water, for redefining the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below color code in XML file

0xff888888 - GRAY.

Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) for color

Comment: I think it's this is an ugly way of doing it, but there really doesn't seem to be any better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same thing, so I put together this simple resource file based on the Android help doc listed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="sysBlack">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="sysBlue">#FF0000FF</color>
    <color name="sysCyan">#FF00FFFF</color>
    <color name="sysDkGray">#FF444444</color>
    <color name="sysGray">#FF888888</color>
    <color name="sysGreen">#FF00FF00</color>
    <color name="sysLtGray">#FFCCCCCC</color>
    <color name="sysMagenta">#FFFF00FF</color>
    <color name="sysRed">#FFFF0000</color>
    <color name="sysTransparent">#00000000</color>
    <color name="sysWhite">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="sysYellow">#FFFFFF00</color>
</resources>
```